# Is there any way to provide a shipping address to @paypal/react-paypal-js createOrder prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

```
<PayPalScriptProvider options={{ "client-id": "", currency: "MXN" }}>
   <PayPalButtons
       createOrder={createOrder}
       onApprove={(data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)}
       onError={error => console.log(error)}/>
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

I'm calling a createOrder function like this :

```
const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        value: 100.00
                    },
                    description: "asdasda",
                }
            ],
            intent: "CAPTURE",
        }
        )
    }
```

I want to send a pre-set shipping address.

What I've tried:

Sending it in purchase_units array like this:

```
purchase_units: [
   {
       amount: {
          value: 100.00
       },
       shipping: {
         shipping_detail: {
           address : {
                //here goes the address
           }
         }
       }
  }
],
```

I've also tried sending it into payee object but it didn't work.

So, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it just adding this:

```
const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
return actions.order.create({
  application_context: {
    shipping_preferences: 'SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS', //Just add this and it will take the address
  },
  purchase_units: [
    {
      amount: { value: parseInt(`${total}.0`) },
      description: `Cuadroy ${cantidad} cuadros 20x20 ${marco}`,
      shipping: {
        address: {
          address_line_1: calle,
          address_line_2: colonia,
          admin_area_2: municipio,
          admin_area_1: estado,
          postal_code: cp,
          country_code: country,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  intent: 'CAPTURE',
});
```

All i need was adding application context object and set shipping preferences to SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS and thats it.

ALSO i have changed it shipping_detail to shipping like the other user said.

Answer (score 1):

[Testing here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client), the following works:

```
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '88.44'
                        },
                        shipping:{
                            name:{
                                full_name:'John Doe'
                            },
                            address: {
                                address_line_1: '1200 Main St',
                                address_line_2: 'Unit 10',
                                admin_area_2: 'Phoenix',
                                admin_area_1: 'AZ',
                                postal_code: '85001',
                                country_code: 'US'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
```

Documentation is at [purchase_unit_request](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request) (key name: shipping)

And: [shipping_detail](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-shipping_detail) (shipping_detail is the object name, not a key name)